# How can I test helper method that uses capture?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, helper

I have a helper that performs:

```
def send_to_block(value, &block)
   capture(value, &block)
end
```

When writing a test:

```
value_received = nil
send_to_block('test') do |value|
   value_received = value
end
value_received.should == 'test'
```

I am getting the following exception:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Kernel::DISABLED
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that your actual test? I thought you needed helper.send_to_block in RSpec.

Comment: Added an answer w/ link and example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the helper object as described in: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-11/docs/helper-specs/helper-spec

Something along these lines should be what you're after:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe MyHelper do
  describe "#send_to_block" do
    it "should do something" do
      helper.send_to_block('test').should == 'I have no idea what this should be'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, missed the &block in the argument list.

Comment: Any idea why I am getting "undefined local variable or method `helper'"

Comment: I see now, I need to move my test to helpers for 'helper' to be available.

Comment: What version of RSpec are you using and where did you define the helper? According to the docs it needs to be in spec/helpers or use `:type => :helper` in the example group.

Comment: Also, doing the test like I wrote works now. so you don't need to actually test the output, you can also test the parameter.

Comment: And just to add, since my helper test was in lib. It's possible to make it work there using :type => :helper. thanks for the help :)